# Correct AppEngine Golang package for OAuth2 provider

Tags: google-app-engine, go

What's the correct way to use OAuth with

If I use `context.Context` from `golang.org/x/net/context`, the error is:

```
"golang.org/x/net/context".Context does not implement "appengine".Context (missing Call method)
```

But if I use `appengine.Context` from `appengine` (SDK), the error is:

```
cannot use oauth2.NewClient(c) (type *http.Client) as type "golang.org/x/net/context".Context in argument to provider.Client:
*http.Client does not implement "golang.org/x/net/context".Context (missing Deadline method)
```

if I use `oauth2.NoContext`, the runtime error is

```
Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: not an App Engine context
```

both tested using Go 1.4 and 1.7b3

using this piece of code:

```
func Public_YoutubeOauth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    provider, csrf := getOAuth(r)
    gets, err := url.ParseQuery(r.URL.RawQuery)
    if RenderHtmlIfError(w,err) {
        return
    }
    if csrf != gets.Get(`state`) {
        RenderHtmlError(w,`incorrect CSRF state`)
        return
    }
    code := gets.Get(`code`)
    token, err := provider.Exchange(c, code) // error here
    if RenderHtmlIfError(w,err) {
        return
    }
    RenderHtml(w,`page`,map[string]interface{`token`:token})
}
```

the `provider` was:

```
&oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     `aaa`,
        ClientSecret: `bbb`,
        RedirectURL:  url + `/foo/youtube_oauth`,
        Scopes: []string{
            `openid`,
            `email`,
            `profile`,
            `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`,
        },
        Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
    }
```

What's the correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

1. Change all `"appengine` imports to `"google.golang.org/appengine`
2. Keep use `context.Context` (from `golang.org/x/net/context`) instead of `appengine.Context`